# AngularJS: cost of deep watching infrequently changed object trees

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs

I am working on a complex widget with a "preferences" object tree with 50-100 objects and 3-5 properties in each object. Each property is watched by Angular and controls how some aspects of the data are displayed.

The user can directly change each preference via inputs in the widget and I want to save the preference tree when changed.

The Angular way to do this is to `$watch(preferences, <save function>, true)`, but the documentation does warn:

> This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse
>   memory and performance implications.

The alternative is to add event handlers to each of the input that alters the preference object, which is quite error prone.

If the preferences are very infrequently changed, would the performance penalty of the deep watch be significant enough to justify implementing the alternative?

Comment: How is the widget you're writing performing?  Is there a performance problem yet?

Comment: Without watching the preferences object, there are 2325 watchers firing for each data change which takes 0.25s on my machine. So it's not fast and I would not want to make it any slower.

Comment: How difficult would it be to implement the alternative?

Comment: Seems that Google changed their strategy in Angular 2.  `$watch` was removed; change management is now automatic and much more performant.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34570122/102937